# isKindOfClass on two classes (not instances)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance

Class named B inherits from A (B : A)

```
[[B class] isKindOfClass:[A class]]
```

**returns NO**

doing

```
[[B new] isKindOfClass:[A class]]
```

**returns YES**

so the left caller must be an instance, but how to do the same with a Class ?

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4251473/1187415 provides a method using the Objective-C runtime functions.

Comment: Well, this question doesn't agree with how I know this works. Also, I just tried and `[Foo isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]` returns `YES`, provided that `Foo` inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: But `[NSMutableString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` returns `NO`.

Comment: Also `[NSMutableString isKindOfClass: [NSMutableString class]]` returns `NO`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

is indeed an instance method (note the -) and won't work on the class

```
+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

is a class method (note the +) and that's what you're looking for.

But wait ! [NSObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) tells us “Refer to a class only by its name when it is the receiver of a message. In all other cases [...] use the class method.”

So you will use :

```
[B isSubclassOfClass:[A class]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Class` is like an object, it's able to respond to many messages, to print a description and also a `Class` has a class property. But the class property points back to the class itself, that's why if you do something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSObject class]class]);
```

You get "NSObject". You think to have a `NSObject` instance, but instead you haven't one.

`Class` overrides `isKindOfClass:` and `isMemberOfClass:`, that's why `[[NSObject isKindOfClass: [NSObject class]]` returns `NO`, because `NSObject` is a `Class`, not a `NSObject` instance.

The way to test it is to call the method on instances, or like already posted in the comments to use [Objective-C runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251286/how-to-tell-if-a-class-inherits-from-nsobject-objective-c/4251473#4251473)