# Figure out if element of an Array<Any> descend from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've an array that contains different types of `Any`, i.e. `Array<Any>`. Now, I send this array and iterate over it. All elements in this array that descends from `NSObject` has to be wrapped.

However, I am not sure, how to figure out, if an elements descend from `NSObject`

1. I saw this answer here [How to tell if a Class inherits from NSObject (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251286/how-to-tell-if-a-class-inherits-from-nsobject-objective-c) - however, I'm afraid, it will lead to runtime error on pure Swift objects.
2. I've also tried `isKindOfClass`, but that seems to be returning `true` in all the cases, for all kind of element, like `Int`, `Dictionary`, `Mirror` etc

Below is how array and its type look. HelloTest inherit from NSObject

[image: This is how array and its type look. HelloTest inherit from NSObject]

**PS**

1. I've to write this code in Objective-C
2. I've this array traversing from `Swift` code to `ObjC` code, thus, I can have all kind of Swift objects in this array.

Comment: The problem is that in the Apple Swift world many Swift types bridge to Objective-C types `[AnyObject]` to `NSArray`, `Int` to `NSNumber`.  Why exactly do you need to do a type check for `NSObject`.  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I need to check for NSObject descendants to ensure I am able to use `objc/runtime` methods on them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use optional binding in Swift

```
for obj in array {
    if let obj = obj as NSObject {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For Arrays/NSArray in Objective-C basically all objects either inherit from NSObject or conform to the NSObject Protocol so `isKindOfClass:NSObject` will basically always be true.

Comment: Have to write it in ObjC - it is possible there?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to have ints in an NSArray in Objective-C though. Otherwise most classes in objective-c will be a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: I've this array traversing from `Swift` code to `ObjC` code, thus, I can have all kind of Swift objects in this array.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe Int's get converted to a NSNumber which is a subclass of NSObject. Try it out.

Comment: Added image for better understanding of elements in the array.

Comment: It seems like all of these are just bridged classes, which are all subclasses of NSObject which is why `isKindOfClass` returns true.

Comment: Well, you may be write.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays may contain only objects.  You won't find an unwrapped anything in an array, and all of the wrapper types (`NSNumber`, `NSValue`, etc.), like *nearly everything else* descend from `NSObject`.

So, in order to tell what you have, you'll need a more specific question, like a disjunction of the wrapper's you expect to find, or a disjunction of the custom objects (e.g. Mirror)